# Unable to access S3 objects via Cloudfront URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I am unable to access S3 objects and Bucket via cloud front URL.

I have created CLOUDFRONT Distribution ( Web ) and setup origin path to media folder in my S3 bucket. ( /media)
CF url is pointing to bucket/media , but i am unable to access it from my web application as well as browser.

I am trying to access like below:

http://d1xdpXXXXX.cloudfront.net/media/images/Tiger.jpg

Tiger.jpg can be accessed via s3 url.

I also tried http://d1xdpXXXXX.cloudfront.net but i am getting below error:

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
<BucketName>d1xdpwiqgrffrd.cloudfront.net</BucketName>
<RequestId>484BBB2F7907172F</RequestId>
<HostId>+bLr4Qx+uawbq4YNIOuKGCQVDGQQQsifGnNt9J5Pn+r3mqbDiVYcpNZRUfnCyPnHxewfMVp3QYc=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Please help.

[CF Distribution settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H6aN.png)

[Access denied error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS3zA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already added the path in cloudfront origin.

So, you don't have to add that in cloudfront url you are using to download.

Just use

```
http://d1xdpXXXXX.cloudfront.net/images/Tiger.jpg
```

as `/media` is already part of the distribution.